# ROBLOX ContextActionService giving me"Argument 2 missing or nil"

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local ContextActionService=game:GetService("ContextActionService")
local Part=game.Workspace.Part

local function onButtonPress()
    Part.BrickColor=BrickColor.new("New Yeller")
end

ContextActionService:BindAction("turnbrickyellow", onButtonPress(), true, Enum.KeyCode.T)
```

I tried researching then realise I did nothing wrong, expect it to run and put a button somewhere to press for phones. BTW my script is localscript, so yea.

Comment: you are calling `onButtonPress` remove the `()` at the end of  it in `ContextActionService:BindAction("turnbrickyellow", onButtonPress(), true, Enum.KeyCode.T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextActionService:BindAction` takes a `functionToBind`, a function which is called each time the input is fired.

In your code, you do `ContextActionService:BindAction("turnbrickyellow", onButtonPress(), true, Enum.KeyCode.T)` where you call `onButtonPress()` as a function (when you do this, the return value of that function is essentially `nil`)

Instead, you would want to do

```lua
ContextActionService:BindAction("turnbrickyellow", onButtonPress, true, Enum.KeyCode.T)
```